# Mobile first and responsive design

Tags: html, web-applications, mobile

I am reading about these new techniques for making websites. However all they do (at least those I find) are trying to fit a lot of buzzwords in their fairly short articles and nobody really shows good examples of it.

How do you support a webpage that responsively adapts the users device? With responsive design you are using media queries to add different stylesheets. However the amount of content and markup is in many cases very different between a mobile and a full webpage. So how do you do you support both? I guess you do not use the stylesheets to hide content with the `display:none` since it still require the content of the full page to be loaded and it makes constraints on the markup. So do you use server side technology to give people different pages or what?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you architecture, you have a few approaches:

- If there is not a lot of extra content, you can indeed use display:none
- You can use ajax to request different content from server
- You can use something like header detection on server - http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html to figure out

In general, for simple sites you would use first technique, while it might not be best (pushing extra content to mobile user), it's the easiest.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is best to develop mobile first and add content for more capable devices when they need it. The worst you can actually do is to hide stuff for small screens. Why? Because this approach also hides the features if you are just using a small window on desktop. Mobile users don't want less content, they want content which is more streamlined.